# When I want to move my player with the keyboard, once I let go of the arrow keys the player keeps moving. (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

```
public function keyD(p:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace(p.keyCode);
    //a=65  d=68 w=87 s=83 
    //to program the 4 arrow keys
    if (p.keyCode==Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        vx=-5;
    }
    else if (p.keyCode==Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        vx=5;
    }
    else if (p.keyCode==Keyboard.UP)
    {
        vy=-5;
    }
    else if (p.keyCode==Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        vy=5;
    }
}
public function keyU(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    //we want to program the 4 arrow keys
    if (p.keyCode==Keyboard.LEFT) //Make player move left
    {
        vx=0;
    }
    else if (p.keyCode==Keyboard.RIGHT) //Make player move right
    {
        vx=0;
    }
    else if (p.keyCode==Keyboard.UP) //Make player move up
    {
        vy=0;
    }
    else if (p.keyCode==Keyboard.DOWN) //Make player move down
    {
        vy=0;
    }
}



public function gameLoop(e:Event):void
{
    //this function is called 24 times each second

    p.x+=vx;//move the player horizontally
    p.y+=vy;//move the player vertically
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parameter in `keyU` is named `e` and not `p`, therefore your switch-case operator compares null with something. Replace `e` with `p` or all `p`s with `e`s.

Comment: if this fixed your problem, you can mark the answer as correct by clicking the green check mark. Thanks.